# Laravel 4: How to install Meido Form and HTML ports from Laravel 3

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-4

I wanted to use Form and HTML classes in Laravel 4, so I went to Meido's GitHub pages for the [HTML](https://github.com/meido/html) and [Form](https://github.com/meido/form) ports. I followed the instructions to the letter.  I added these lines to my app's providers:

```
'Meido\Form\FormServiceProvider',
'Meido\HTML\HTMLServiceProvider',
```

I added these lines to my aliases:

```
'Form' => 'Meido\Form\FormFacade',
'HTML' => 'Meido\HTML\HTMLFacade',
```

This is `composer.json'

```
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
        "meido/form": "1.1.*",
         "meido/html": "1.1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

I ran `composer install` as instructed.  Composer told me to run `update` so I did.  Composer updated a number of dependencies, including some of the core of Laravel 4.  My app is now completely broken.  I just get a white screen on any page.  I don't get any error messages to debug the problem.  Even the view source is blank.  How can I fix this?

Comment: have you checked your server logs?

Comment: No, not yet.  I have to find the logs.  I'm on a Mac using localhost. Do you know where they're located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel 4 is still undergoing development, and I've found that the updated dependencies won't always work correctly without a fresh install of some of the files.

The main files that affected by this will be:

/app/config/app.php
/start.php

I'd recommend grabbing a fresh copy of these files from the repository and replacing them in your project, then using composer to update again and regenerate your autoload files (composer dump-autoload).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do I need anything else other than `start.php`

Comment: I see app.php.  There is now a start folder.  Do I update the entire folder?

Comment: /app/config/app.php - those are the only two I've had to change, but I can't promise there aren't others.

Comment: The problem  was that I was using Beta 1.  Beta 2 works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `composer dump-autoload` and see if the problem goes away.

I have a package named [Laravel 4 Powerpack](https://github.com/laravelbook/laravel4-powerpack) - it combines many of the L3 helper classes (HTML, Form, Str) into a single package. Detailed installation instruction is provided on the github page.

To get a new app up to speed, I've also created the [Laravel 4 starter template](https://github.com/laravelbook/laravel4-starter) - it combines Powerpack as well as Ardent O/RM enhancer.

Even though L4 is in second beta, it's still undergoing heavy active development. After running "composer update" I find my apps broken from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else watching this you can easily fix it with git by reverting to a tag.

```
git tag -l
```

Look for the tag you want (v4.0.0-BETA3 in my case.)

```
git checkout v4.0.0-BETA3
```

This will leave you in a "detached head" state so you need to create a new branch if you want to continue:

git checkout -b v4.0.0-BETA3

That particular tag worked for me.